# Critical Hits on Oath of glory paladin Inspiring Smite is dice doubled?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, critical-hit, temporary-hit-points

When rolling a critical hit does all the dice associated with that attack double or just damage from the attack?

> **Inspiring Smite.** Immediately after you deal damage to a creature with your Divine Smite feature, you can use your Channel Divinity as a bonus action and distribute temporary hit points to creatures of your choice within 30 feet of you, which can include you. The total number of temporary hit points equals 2d8 + your level in this class, divided among the chosen creatures however you like.

Checking to see if the [Oath of Glory](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin#OathofGlory) Paladin Channel Divinity feature provides **4d8+Level** instead of just **2d8+Level**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### The critical hit does not double the temporary HPs provided by Inspiring Smite feature.

The amount of temporary HPs granted by the Inspiring Smite feature is not linked to the amount of the damage dealt, but only to the fact that you succeeded in damaging a creature with the Divine Smite feature.

The text of Inspiring Smite says:

> The total number of temporary hit points equals 2d8 + your level in this class, divided among the chosen creatures however you like.

The amount of the temp HPs is fixed to 2d8 + your level: hence it is independent on the damage dealt. If it was the case, the rule would have specified so.

Comment: Interesting point being 2d8 assumed similar to divine smite.

Comment: @Troommate Yes, I noticed the same: it seems to me that a d8 is a paladin-themed die...